# Does Spring Data Jdbc enables join foreign key rather than id's?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Tried lots of options but all the time i've got wrong join's. instead of get the actual status_name by its id populated in the 'status' column of supplier_contracts table the repository returns join i'ds of the 2 tables. so How do i retrive the status_name by the int of the status column  supplierContractRepository.findById(3L)?

Statuses Entity

```
 CREATE TABLE `contract_statuses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

public class ContractStatuses {
  
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String name;

    public ContractStatuses(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Contracts Entity

```
    CREATE TABLE `suppliers_contracts` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `supplier` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `cabs_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `attorny_end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `number_of_payments` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `payment_amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `comments` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
      `close_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

@Table("suppliers_contracts")
public class SupplierContract {
    @Id
    Long id;
    Long supplier;
    Long cabsId;
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
    int paymentAmount;
    Date attornyEndDate;
    int numberOfPayments;
    String comments;
    Date closeDate;
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "id")
    ContractStatuses status;
   
    public SupplierContract(Long id, Long supplier, Long cabsId, Date startDate, Date endDate,Date attornyEndDate, int numberOfPayments, int paymentAmount,
                            String comments, Date closeDate,ContractStatuses status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.cabsId = cabsId;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.attornyEndDate = attornyEndDate;
        this.numberOfPayments = numberOfPayments;
        this.paymentAmount = paymentAmount;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.closeDate = closeDate;
        this.status = status;

    }
}
        //Getters and setters here

@GetMapping("/getContracts")
    public Optional<SupplierContract> getSupp(){
       Optional<SupplierContract>  contract = supplierContractRepository.findById(3L);
        return contract ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various options:

1. The default variant is to load the status with a separate call to a separate `ContractStatusRepository`. Since those statuses might not change very often you might consider caching for this.
2. If you only want the status and don't care about the contract you can add an additional method to your repository with a `@Query` annotation which selects the two fields of the status based on the `id` of a contract using a SQL join.
3. **This one works only for Read Only access!**
   You can create another entity `ReadOnlyContract` which contains the `ContractStatuses` reference, marked as an embedded attribute. You can now map this to a view containing the additional status fields.
   In order to avoid accidental use of writing methods you should have the repository inherit from `Repository` and add only the read methods you actually need.

Comment: thank you but i'm obviously missing something because when i  added `@Embedded(onEmpty = USE_NULL)
    ContractStatuses statuses;`  i'm getting `A database object name must not be null or empty` or `Unknown column 'suppliers_contracts.name' in 'field list'` depend on how i shaped the object..

Comment: Sounds like the view does not match the expected structure. Could you create a fresh question with the object structure, view and stack trace?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076453/embeded-entity-for-read-only-spring-data-jdbc

Answer (score -1):

You should use DB relationship between `SupplierContract` and `ContractStatuses` class.

i.e use `ContractStatuses contractStatuses;` instead of `int status;` and use relationship one-to-many after this when you query `findAll()` you will get `ContractStatuses` from where you can get `status_name`.

Comment: But the relationship is many to one cause SupplierContract can have only one status_id at certain point of time while some status_id may obviously have many contracts.. so how it can be reflected when i want to execute supplierContract.findAll() and get the status_name column as well?

Comment: You have to declare relationships on both side `@ManyToOne` on SupplierContract side and `@OneToMany` on ContractStatuses side. see (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships) for further info

Comment: There is no @ManyToOne Annotation in Spring data jdbc

Comment: This answer seems to assume JPA which is not used in the question.