# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot query by nested property" when using query derivation for property on nested entity

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

This is a follow-up question to this: [Reference to another aggregate vs. sub-entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73906592/reference-to-another-aggregate-vs-sub-entity?noredirect=1#comment130608528_73906592)

I have the following Aggregate:

```
Evaluation (root)
|
|__Employee (entity)
|  |_SupervisorId (value object)
|
|__Year (value object)
|
|__ExpiryDate (value object)
```

I have an EvaluationRepository-Interface where i use query-derivation to read Evaluations.
The method looks like this:

```
Set<Evaluation> findAllByYearAndExpiryDateIsNullAndEmployee_SupervisorId(Integer year, Long supervisorId);
```

i get this Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot query by nested property: employee.supervisorId
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.JdbcQueryCreator.validateProperty(JdbcQueryCreator.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.JdbcQueryCreator.validate(JdbcQueryCreator.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.PartTreeJdbcQuery.<init>(PartTreeJdbcQuery.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JdbcQueryLookupStrategy.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JdbcQueryLookupStrategy.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103)
    ... 136 more
```

This is the line in JdbcQueryCreator where the exception is thrown:

```
if (!path.getParentPath().isEmbedded() && path.getLength() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("Cannot query by nested property: %s", path.getRequiredPersistentPropertyPath().toDotPath()));
        }
```

When i write a custom query via @Query it works.
What is the problem with query derivation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the problem with query derivation here?

The problem is simply that this is [not implemented yet for Spring Data JDBC](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1227).